# Visual Studio 2017 CMake issues with UWP projects

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, uwp

I am currently having issues with Visual Studios 2017 enterprise edition not being able to generate / compile code for UWP projects using CMake,

the Error:
 - A Windows Store component with CMake requires both the Windows Desktop SDK
   as well as the Windows Store '10.0' SDK.  Please make sure that you have
   both installed

I have tracked down the issue over a period of time searching it seems that the version of CMake visual studio is using cant properly find Windows 10 SDK or Windows Desktop SDK, i tried to exchange the version of cmake VS2017 is using for a newer version e.g. ( I tried both 3.8 and 3.9 ) both worked to a certain extent until post a parse error in the output for cmake target info extraction.

i found the reason for that is because VS2017 is using a custom version of CMake - 3.7.20170106-gd3236-dirty-MSVC_2

does anyone have a work around to get UWP projects to work with VS 2017 CMake.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that it's a known issue.

> The 3.7.2 version of CMake bundled with Visual Studio 2017 (latest update) cannot on its own find the Visual Studio 2017 build tools. Using CMake 3.8.1 (current CMake release), the tools can be found no problem.

You could see more detailed information from here: [Visual Studio 2017 CMake Build Tools Bug](https://gist.github.com/andschwa/391a82050118ea2862858a8a34e115c5)

So, please try to use the [CMake 3.8](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/release/3.8.html)